# Confusion over unexpected Math.cos behavior in Javascript

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry

The cosine of 90 degrees is 0.

I understand Javascript's `Math.cos` takes radians, so I've tried:

```
Math.cos(90 * Math.PI / 180)
```

Why does this yield `6.123233995736766e-17` instead of 0?

Answer (score 1):

`6.123233995736766e-17` is essentially `0`. It's `0.00000000000000006123233995736766`. That kind of minor error is completely normal when working with IEEE floating point numbers.

The solution is to never compare numbers exactly, but compare if they are within a range that you expect. EG.

```
var result = Math.cos(90 * Math.PI / 180);
if ( Math.abs( result - 0 ) < 1e-16 ) {
    // Test passed, result is effectively 0
}
```

The `- 0` does nothing, but more generally `- x` is how you would compare to `x`. You are trying to compare to `0`, so I used `- 0`, but you could leave that off and get the same result.